# Double mapping cylinder- a point set question

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, examples-counterexamples

We have the following set up:
$X_0 \subset X_{\pm} \subset X$. Also interiors of $X_\pm$ cover $X$. Now let $Z$ be the double mapping cylinder of the maps $X_- \leftarrow X_0 \rightarrow X_+$. Define $N(X_-,X_+)=X_-\times 0 \cup X_0 \times I \cup X_+ \times 1$ with the subspace topology inherited from $X \times I$. Now there is a canonical bijective map $\alpha : Z \to N$ over $X$. The author (on page 86 in Algebraic Topology [book](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/diecktop.pdf) by Tammy Tom Dieck) claims that this map is an h-equivalence.
At first glance I thought that $\alpha$ is a homeomorphism, but now my intuition says that it need not be. Could someone please help me in constructing a counter example ?

- Basis for my intuition : Let $Y=\mathbb{R}$, $Y_1=\mathbb{R_+} \cup 0$ and $Y_2=(Y-Y_1) \cup [5, \infty)$. Let $Y$ have the usual topology and let $Y_1,Y_2$ have the subspace topology. Then the topology on $Y$ induced by constructing the quotient space of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ (by identifying pairs of point in intersection $Y_1 \cap Y_2$) is not the same as the usual topology on $Y$.

However I am unable to construct a similar example for the required case. Thanks !

Comment: Maybe $X=I, X_+=(0,1], X_-=[0,1), X_0=(0,1)$. In the quotient topology, the point $(0,0)$ has more neighborhoods than in the subspace topology of $I\times I$.

Comment: @StefanHamcke Sorry I did not understand how this works as an example. Could you please give an open set in quotient topology which is not open in subspace topology ? If I am not wrong, sets like $[0,0.1) \times 0$ are neither open in the quotient topology, nor in the subspace topology.

Comment: Let's say we glue $(0,y)\in X_+\times I$ to $y\in X\times\{0\}$, we glue $(1,y)\in X_-\times I$ to $y\in X\times\{1\}$, and finally we glue $(1,y)\in X_+\times I$ to $(0,y)\in X_+\times I$ if $y\in X_0$. Then the bijection $a$ from this quotient space to $X\times I$ sends $(s,y)\in X_+\times I$ to $(s/2,y)$. Now $(0,0)$ has only neighborhoods containing a ball around $(0,0)$. One neighborhood in the quotient topology is the set $\{(s,y)\mid s<y<1/2\}\cup\{(0,0)\}$, this is not open in the subspace topology.